# How to find first and last non-blank value in a table based on condition in Excel and convert it to text

Tags: excel

I have searched online but none of the answers over there seem to solve my problem.

So basically I have a row (say A1:E2) withh the square feet

```
                                     Office Residential   Retail    Hotel   
 Investment Period (start/end)        1y/3y  1y/2y        1y/2y     1y/2y
```

And then in another range (A3:G8) a table built like that:

```
          Year 1         Year 1      Year 2      Year 2      Year 3     Year 3
          1st Sem.       2nd Sem.    1st Sem.   2nd Sem.    1st Sem.    2nd Sem.
Office      25%            25%                    25%                    25%    
Residetial  35%            35%                    30%       
Retail      20%            20%         20%        40%
Hotel       20%            20%         20%        40%
```

Now, in B2:E2 I have personally put the text like 1y/2y, 2y/3y and so on. Instead, i would like some kinfd of index match formula (or lookup) that does it for me, since the table is much bigger than that. Is there anything that could help me?

I have tried (in B2) something like =INDEX($A3$:$G$8,MATCH(B2,INDEX($A3$1:$A$8<>"",0),0)) but it does not work properly... and then there is the problem of converting the value found in the corresponding year start and year end.

I hope I was exaustive! Thanks

Comment: You might need helper columns. Looks like you need to find the first and last non-blank cell in a row. Would help if you could add a row above your table with your  1y, 2y, 3y.

Comment: once found the formula for finding the correct cell, then it will be easy to implement your suggestion. The problem is that i dont know how to find the numbers i want

Comment: Find it hard to believe you can't google. See suggested answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used some helper columns here in G and H, but of course you could dispense with and put the result directly in I.

G3 and down

```
=INDEX($B$1:$E$1,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX((B3:E3<>""),0),0))
```

H3 and down

```
=INDEX($B$1:$E$1,MATCH(LOOKUP(2,1/(B3:E3<>""),B3:E3),B3:E3,0))
```

I3 and down is straightforward concatenation

```
=G3&"/"&H3
```

You need to add your abbreviations in the top row (or somewhere at least) for this approach (could be hidden somewhere).

[image]

Comment: Thank you. It works perfectly. I did not think in that way... super!